# Mismatch between C++ symbols and Q symbols

Tags: c++, kdb, q-lang

I'm having some trouble when returning symbols from C++ code. I made a small example that illustrates the problem.

We export the following function:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) K getSym(K x) {
    return ks((S)"sym");
}
```

And then call it from Q:

```
q)asdf:(`our_dll 2:(`getSym;1))[1]
q)asdf
`sym
q)asdf = `sym
0b
q)asdf = `$string asdf
0b
q)0N!asdf
`sym
`sym
q)(string asdf) = (string `sym)
111b
```

Why are the two values unequal?

This is 32-bit KDB+ 3.2.

Comment: what is the output of 0N!asdf;

Comment: sometimes the console can obscure the actual underlying shape/type of a variable. 0N! will display the true value

Comment: I tried this code and it works.

Comment: I added the output of `0N!asdf` to the question. @KhouriGiordano , which version of KDB are you using?

Comment: It's Win32 and on start-up, Q says "KDB+ 3.2 2015.04.07". I got the `k.h` and `q.lib` files that are linked from [the wiki](http://code.kx.com/wiki/Cookbook/ExtendingWithC). I had never heard of Q until this question, tho I've made plenty of dynamically loaded DLLs.

Comment: Hm...interesting. I used their `k.h` and `c.obj` files.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a version of q prior to 2.4, you need to intern C string using the `ss()` function before passing it to `ks()`.  You should not see this problem with the recent versions.